# grass gis- ERROR: nwalk (7000001) > maxw (7000000)!

Tags: grass-gis

i want to make r.sim.water (hydrological modelling) in Grass Gis, and this ERROR: nwalk (7000001) > maxw (7000000)! always appears, any ideas how to solve it?

number of cells of dem is below 7000000.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really familiar with this function. But a quick glance at the [grass manual for r.sim.water](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/r.sim.water.html), the parameter nwalk is defined as,

```
nwalk=integer
Number of walkers, default is twice the no. of cells
```

It also says, under the heading Error Messages,

```
If the module fails with
ERROR: nwalk (7000001) > maxw (7000000)!
then a lower nwalk parameter value has to be selected.
```

so try a lower value of nwalk.

Comment: i tried this before i posted comment, it didn´t work :)

Comment: How was the error message then?

Comment: it was still the same, i tried working in another pc and finally it worked